# REST Client Sub-resources return AbstractMethodError when invoked

Tags: java, resteasy, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

EDIT: Problem was `quarkus-rest-client-reactive`, see my answer.

From my understanding of the MicroProfile REST Client available in Quarkus, I should be able to define sub-resources in my REST client interface that will allow me to nest resources under each other like so.

```java
package org.acme.example

import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RegisterRestClient;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@RegisterRestClient
@Path("/api/foo")
public interface FoosService {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Uni<List<Foo>> getAll();

    @Path("/{id}")
    FooService foo(@PathParam("id") String id);
}

public interface FooService {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Uni<Foo> toRepresentation();
}
```

However, when I inject and call the client interface in my code, it throws a `AbstractMethodError` on the `client.foo("bar").toRepresentation()` call.

```java
@Path("/bar")
public class BarResource {
    @RestClient
    FoosResource client;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Foo getBar() {
        return client.foo("bar").toRepresentation();
    }
}
```

All my research into this seems to suggest that this is possible, but there are no specific examples for Quarkus that show client sub-resources.

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci [Keycloak Admin API Client](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/integration/admin-client) is a good example of a RESTEasy Client using the Client Proxy Framework that includes sub-resources (granted the RESTEasy version in that client is 3.13.2, while the latest Quarkus version uses 4.6.1, but none of the RESTEasy changelogs mention any change in the relevant behaviour.)

Comment: I assume that you have copy-paste error but both interfaces are named FooService

Comment: did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Something that I failed to mention in the original post was that I was using the Reactive extension for the REST Client, which appears to cause the issue.

Using the synchronous extension allows the proxy to correctly build sub-resource proxies. There is probably more configuration that needs to be set for the reactive version to work with sub-resources.

Answer (score 0):

Subresources in general work with Quarkus Rest Client Reactive.
You can take a look at the test we have in the Quarkus codebase for an example (one problem is that it most probably uses more features than you need): https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/2.1.0.Final/extensions/resteasy-reactive/rest-client-reactive/deployment/src/test/java/io/quarkus/rest/client/reactive/subresource/SubResourceTest.java#L28

I don't see anything particularly wrong with your code sample. If you could create a GitHub issue in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues with a minimal reproducer of your problem, that would help me a lot in either fixing it or helping you.

Comment: got an reproducer for the same issue with sub-sub-resources here: https://github.com/lordvlad/quarkus/compare/2.5.1.Final...lordvlad:subsubresource-bug-reproducer?expand=1; I also tried to annotate the `SubClient` with `@Path("/")` and `@RegisterRestClient`, neither of which helped